# MS Access SQL: Data from Two Columns on One Row Becomes Data in One Column on Two Rows

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a table with oil wellbore perforation data on it (where perforations were made in the well for oil to come through). The columns for this table are the following:

well_name, D_Top_Perf, D_Bot_Perf, x_top, y_top, x_bot, y_bot, sand_layer.

I'm trying to map the x-y data on a map and my line connections are made from the x_top/y_top of one sand layer to the x_top/y_top of the next sand layer (ordered by D_Top_Perf) for each well. As it is set up, I can successfully plot most of the data. The issue comes from when either a well only has one sand layer (I only see the x_top/y_top point... no line connection can be made to other points) or it's the last sand layer of the well (again, I only see the data point for the last x_top/y_top sand layer... nothing to connect to). To fix this, I need to incorporate the x_bot and y_bot data.

I'd like to insert a row, every other row, with the x_bot and y_bot data in the same columns as the x_top and y_top data.

Example:

Current Table Format:

```
well_name  D_Top_Perf  D_Bot_Perf  x_top  y_top  x_bot  y_bot  sand_layer
A101           100         200     10000  10000  10010  10010      X 
A101           200         300     10010  10010  10020  10020      Y 
A101           300         400     10020  10020  10030  10030      Z
```

What I'd like it to look like:

```
well_name  D_Top_Perf  D_Bot_Perf  x_top  y_top  sand_layer
A101           100         200     10000  10000    X
A101           100         200     10010  10010    X
A101           200         300     10010  10010    Y
A101           200         300     10020  10020    Y
A101           300         400     10020  10020    Z
A101           300         400     10030  10030    Z
```

With the new format, wells with only one layer or the last sand layers of wells will still have two x-y points so they can connect and be plotted.

How would I go about doing this in MS Access SQL?

Thanks,

-Andrew

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply run a union query:

```
SELECT well_name, D_Top_Perf, D_Bot_Perf, x_top, y_top, sand_layer
FROM currentTable
ORDER BY sand_layer
UNION ALL
SELECT well_name, D_Top_Perf, D_Bot_Perf, x_bot, y_bot, sand_layer
FROM currentTable
```